# OrmLite - Change the eager level dynamically

Tags: android, ormlite, eager

Currently I am setting the eager level of a foreign collection statically for all queries, by setting an annotation in my object.

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager=true)
private Collection<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

Is there a way to set this eager level dynamically, depending on the query I am making. I would prefer it not to set the eager level always to true. I only need this in some special queries.

Greetings
Tobi

**EDIT:**
Does no answer mean, that this is not possible or does it mean, that nobody knows the answer?